# This my small python program .when button clicks new window opening. how it is possible to in one window only

Tags: python, tkinter

This is small Python button program. My problem was when I am clicking button always opening new window. I want one window execution.

```
from tkinter import *
import sys
def pressed():
    root = Tk()
    root.title('My Window2')
    root.geometry('200x200')
    button = Button(root,text = 'press2',command = pressed2)
    button.pack(pady = 20, padx = 20)

def close():
    quit()
def pressed1():
    print('second window')

def pressed2():
    root = Tk()
    root.title('My Window3')
    root.geometry('200x200')
    button = Button(root,text = 'press3',command = pressed1)
    button.pack(pady = 20, padx = 20)
    button = Button(root,text = 'back',command = pressed)
    button.pack(pady = 20, padx = 20)

root = Tk()
root.title('My Window')
root.geometry('200x200')
button = Button(root,text = 'press',command = pressed)
button2 = Button(root,text = 'Exit',command = close)
button.pack(pady = 20, padx = 20)
button2.pack(pady = 20, padx = 20)
mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

I have not used Tkinter, but here is what looks like is happening.
1. on my win 7 python 2.6 it is Tkinter, not tkinter
2. when you use root = Tk() it is creating a new window; if you remove the root = Tk() from pressed() and pressed2() it uses the original window over again.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what you want, but if you are trying to modify the text, and command associated with the button then you just need to `configure` those attributes.

Something like this should work.  It can be modified to add new buttons instead of reusing the same button.  I made the class inherit from Frame, but you could also choose to inherit from Tk.  (Note: This is Python 3 code)

```
import tkinter

class ButtonPressWindow(tkinter.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tkinter.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        master.title('My Window')
        master.geometry('200x200')

        self.button1 = tkinter.Button(self, text='press', command=self.pressed)
        self.button2 = tkinter.Button(self, text='Exit', command=self.close)

        self.button1.pack(pady=20, padx=20)
        self.button2.pack(pady=20, padx=20)

    def pressed(self):
        self.master.title('My Window2')
        self.master.geometry('200x200')

        self.button1.configure(text='press2', command=self.pressed2)

    def pressed2(self):
        self.master.wm_title('My Window3')
        self.master.geometry('200x200')

        self.button1.configure(text='press3', command=self.pressed3)

    def pressed3(self):
        print("Second window")

    def close(self):
        quit()


root = tkinter.Tk()
btnWindow = ButtonPressWindow(root)
btnWindow.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: My question is when i run this program every thing working fine but when i clicking button it's opening new window for each button i click . i want one window execution means if i press first window button it should be open in that window only.

Comment: My code uses one window and reuses the components (buttons, and window title).  I'm not clear on what you mean by "open in that window only".